Why CustomTab is recommended to use instead of Webview?
Recently while integrating other applications or services into my application, I have seen the Providers are saying that Webview is not recommended and use Custom Tabs like that.
My questions are,

What are all the disadvantages while we use Webview?
Why CustomTabs is suggested instead of Webview?


in the link you attached. I see google talks very clearly about this issue. specifically here
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs?hl=vi#when_should_i_use_custom_tabs

@NguyễnMạnhCường In that link they have mentioned what are the advantages of using customtabs, But we can implement the same thing with Webview also right. Then why many people are saying webview is not recommended?

if your using webview instead of CustomTab it can promote trust as the user can see the URL this is important when the integration is third party login. As the user can safely enter his credentials without worrying also if you use webview even if you use a legit website of not phishing you can intercept his credentials

@RenzSalanga Good point
